# If a collatz sequence doesn't converge, how many odd numbers can its subsequence have?

Tags: collatz-conjecture

Let a Collatz sequence of a natural number $x$ as follow:

$$\{x\}: \begin{cases}
x_0=x\\
x_{n+1} = \begin{cases}
\frac{3x_n+1}{2} \text{ if $x_n$ is odd}\\
\frac{x_n}{2} \text{ if $x_n$ is even}
\end{cases}
\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*
\end{cases}$$

The sequence is said to be convergent iff there exists k such that $x_k=1$. However for the purpose of finding the smallest $x$ such that $\{x\}$ doesn't converge (if there's any), we also say the sequence converges iff there exists k such that $x_k<x$.

Let $f(x,n)$ be the amount of odd numbers in the sequence $\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\}$. Find a function $g(n)$ such that if $f(x,n)\leq g(n)$, $\{x\}$ converges.

I believe such inequality must exist because if there are little enough odd numbers in the $\{x_0,...,x_n\}$ sequence, the sequence *tends to decrease* regardless of where the odd numbers lie in the sequence, and so there will exist $k\leq n$ such that $x_k<x$. However I don't know if anyone had found one.

In case of such $g(n)$ is found, function $h(n)$ is said to be better than $g(n)$ if $h(n)$ sastisfies the property that $g(n)$ has and $h(n)>g(n)$ for all large enough $n$. Then what is the current "best" function?

Comment: Why not just $x_{n+1}=3x_n+1$ (the usual iteration) , if $x_n$ is odd ? It makes no difference.

Comment: @Peter because then there can be subsequences of just odd numbers in the sequence

Comment: "that the sequence does not converge" - this would be a counterexample to the Collatz conjecture , so it is likely that there is no such sequence.

Comment: @Peter I meant "if the sequence does not converge". I've fixed the title, hope it's clearer now